# Bounds for Distribution of X/Y with fixed marginals of X and Y

Tags: probability, distributions, references, joint-distribution, copula

Bound for distribution of sum of RVs with fixed marginals has been discussed, for example in [Best-possible bounds for the distribution of a sum — a problem of Kolmogorov](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00569989).

Is there similar paper discussing bounds for distribution of X/Y with fixed marginals of X and Y?

Comment: I think it is much more dependent on what the distribution of Y is due to division-by-zero fears. However, a quick Google search unearths these two for starters: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0047259X05000357 and http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610920600683689?src=recsys&journalCode=lsta20

Comment: Continuing the thoughts by @Avraham, you can analyze the positive and negative parts of $X$ and $Y$ separately, reducing the question to variables with positive support.  Taking logarithms converts it into a question about a sum of variables.

Comment: Thanks @Avraham! I'm looking for bounds for any distributions. I've searched papers citing paper I mentioned, and I found nothing.